# Где можно найти tutorial для темы WordPress "U-Design" (Версия: 2.13.10)

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, cms, themes

Дали поручение, разобраться с темой WordPress "U-Design" (Версия: 2.13.10), нигде не могу найти документация, подскажите, где ее достать, на ютубе ролике 2х летней давности.

Comment: Её вообще может не быть. Что вы хотите понять в этой теме?

Comment: Она платная к тому же. Вряд ли вам тут смогут помочь. Чтобы ответить на какие-то вопросы, надо иметь исходный код этой темы.

Comment: Судя по описанию на themeforest, документация есть. Заставьте заказчика скачть полный комплект темы, а не только исполняемые файлы (там 2 варианта на themeforest).